# Jquery tablesorter plugin not sorting correct

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some columns with the format:

```
<td>148 kr. </td>
```

The tablesorter plugin does not sort them correct. It is like random.

I also have columns like this one:

```
<td>148 kr. <br>(Oprettelse 49 kr.)</td>
```

Were I want to sort by the first number `148 kr.`

What should I do?

Comment: *The tablesorter plugin does not sort them correct.* How does it sort it and how do you want it to be sorted? I imagine it gets sorted lexicographically where you want it to be sorted numerically. Maybe you have to set up some callback which converts the values into the right format (don't know the plugin though).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a custom parser to format your data and strip out unneeded data. Here is the [basic explanation](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html) of custom parsers. In your case the format function could be something like this:

```
format: function(s) { 
    // strip out everything after the initial number
    var _parts = s.split(' ');
    var _firstPart = _parts[0];
    return _firstPart.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
}
```